# Constant perimeter homotopy between a square and a circle

Tags: homotopy-theory

Is there a relatively simple homotopy between a square and a circle so that the perimeter of the curve is constant during the transformation?

Comment: I don't know if this satisfies your 'relatively simple', but the first quadrant can be written in the classic superellipse form $x^n+y^n=\alpha(n)^n$, where $1\leq n\leq 2$ and $\alpha$ is an 'adjustment' term to keep the perimeter constant ($\alpha(n)^{-1}$ is the quarter-perimeter of the 'unit' superellipse $x^n+y^n=1$).  There isn't any elementary or even near-elementary form I can find for the perimeter of a superellipse, but since you're in a 'square' special case you may be able to coax your math software of choice to give you some special-function form for $\alpha(n)$...

Comment: Good idea, but, unfortunately, the expression for the superellipse perimenter is overwhelming...